# XLAM like file container

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have HTA application which I need to run from my XLAM Addin .
  I have .hta (html) .css .vbs files . Can I put this to into .xlam file and extract from VBA

This functionality will help me to distribute program between users

Comment: No, VBA and HTML/VBC files are 2 completely different things.

Comment: Excel has custom XML which would allow you to easily store all sorts of information.  You can read and write to these files, extract the contents and save them to disk so as long as you have a way of launching the file from VBA (shell) I would imagine that this would meet your needs.